# Webstorm JavaScript and Typescript zen-coding

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, zen

Is it possible just by doing something like that:

If I type `f.name.a.b {{tab press}}` => WebStorm will produce

```
function fname(a, b)
{
}
```

or in case of typescript if I type
`c.Name.a.string {{tab press}}`

=> it will produce:

```
class Name {
    a: string;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like that in WebStorm?

Answer (score 1):

> I is possible to ahieve something like that in webstorm

You can do something quite similar using *live templates* : https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/creating-code-constructs-by-live-templates.html

Various other IDEs commonly call this *snippets*.

Comment: oh thatnks. do u know may is there some sort of `live snippets` that I am looking for is already existed?